# how to put a 3d scan as a simple circulating object on a website?

Tags: 3d, scanning, cinema4d, blender, subpixel-rendering

i'm new to 3d scans and just downloaded POLYCAM yesterday.

what programs are needed for simple editing those files? making it more complex, adding text or atmospheric things, another object.

or: i just want to have the scan in pure, rotating on itself, viewable on a website.

i would like to scan a self built figure and put this as a GIF or object animation (?) on a website. you see an example on this homepage (one click on the logo):

https://sucukundbratwurst.de/

how can i do this?

what program is needed for editing the OBJ or GIB files.

and if i want to arrange each scan with the other one, as a family shooting, i'll do that with?..

in the end, i would like to create new posters, pictures, or campaigns with that technique.

thank you for your help!!

Comment: 3D software is generally off-topic here, so too are software recomendations. Sorry about that. Software that can open OBJ files and animate them, export as video/animation sequences: **Blender** is free open source. Others such as **Cinema4D**, and **Maya**, are not free.  There is also a Blender Stack Exchange if you get stuck or want to ask questions about it.

Comment: it's also quite a broad question with multiple topics, check [ask].

Comment: Oh and those animations on the linked website are actually video images, MP4, and not GIF.

Comment: Thank you Billy Kerr for your support. I'm going to check out Blender in the near future and would be already happy if i could establish a figure digital, put a texture on it and so on. if it's blender, then i go for this tool. thx